# CentOS networking BNX2

Tags: linux, networking, centos

Having some trouble with my NICs. The server starts fine and I can wget/ping etc. However, when I `/etc/init.d/networking restart` I then receive the following error:

```
Bringing up interface eth0: bnx2: fw sync timeout, reset code = 1030009
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Device or resource busy
```

Consequently, the task fails. I have searched around on google users suggesting to disable PNP in the BIOS but I see no option. Here is some system information:

```
$ ethtool -i eth0
driver: bnx2
version: 2.0.8-rh
firmware-version: bc 2.9.1

$ uname -a
Linux host 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Apr 12 18:10:13 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$/sbin/lspci | grep Broadcom
04:00.0 PCI brodge: Broadcom EPB PCI-Express to PCI-X Bridge (rev c3)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5700 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 12)
08:00.0 PCI brodge: Broadcom EPB PCI-Express to PCI-X Bridge (rev c3)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5700 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 12)

$ lsmod | grep bnx2
bnx2i                  81704  0 
cnic                  109512  1 bnx2i
libiscsi2              77765  6 be2iscsi,ib_iser,iscsi_tcp,bnx2i,cxgb3i,libiscsi_tcp
scsi_transport_iscsi2    73945  8 be2iscsi,ib_iser,iscsi_tcp,bnx2i,cxgb3i,libiscsi2
bnx2                  224780  0 
scsi_mod              199001  15 mpt2sas,scsi_transport_sas,mptctl,be2iscsi,ib_iser,iscsi_tcp,bnx2i,cxgb3i,libiscsi2,scsi_transport_iscsi2,scsi_dh,sg,libata,megaraid_sas,sd_mod

$ rmmod bnx2; modprobe bnx2
PCI: Enabling device 0000:05:00.0 (0158 -> 015a)
PCI: Enabling device 0000:09:00.0 (0158 -> 015a)
bnx2: fw sync timeout, reset code = 10300003
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am at a loss.

Comment: You may have a hardware issue.  Do you happen to have a spare NIC to swap out?  What's the model of the bnx2 card (/sbin/lspci)?

Comment: Thanks, for your help - I have updated my post with your request.

Comment: It's been a while but I remember having to do a song and dance to get this NIC to work. Do a `lsmod |grep bcm57` and see if the kernel module is loaded. If not, then you will need to install it. Should be on the install DVD. For some reason the bnx2 driver didn't work for me.

Comment: Since posting I have now updated the BNX2 driver version to: 2.0.23b, still the problem persists. I will take a look at your suggestion. BTW lsmod | grep bcm57 returns nothing.

Comment: I see - I'll update the firmware too.

Comment: can you do an 'lsmod' and see whether the bnx2 kernel module is loaded?  If so, 'rmmod bnx2; modprobe bnx2' (as root) and see if that helps.  You will probably need to restart networking after that.  I had a similar issue with a Dell Poweredge R 710 and re loading the bnx2 driver did the trick

Comment: @Mike I ran those commands I have also installed the BCM5700 updates (http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/netxtreme_desktop.php)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible you're hitting one (or both) of these bugs:

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=680411
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693542

Try the latest kernel from jwilson:

- http://people.redhat.com/jwilson/el5/264.el5/

Answer (score 2):

I have been having some issues with these bnx2 based cards. A fix for me was blacklisting the bnx2i module (this one does iSCSI offloading). If you don't need iSCSI offloading, try unloading bnx2i and blacklisting it in modprobe.conf.

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM: Once OMSA loads, the management tools lose communication with
the NIC. (IPMI seems to be involved)

Solution:

```
srvadmin-services.sh disable
shutdown -r now
update_firmware --yes
srvadmin-services.sh enable
shutdown -r now
```

Find the following link 
http://lists.us.dell.com/pipermail/linux-poweredge/2011-November/045577.html